# What is the ID of nobody user and nogroup group?

Tags: lxc, lxd

When trying LXD, I tried to share a folder from my computer with the LXC Container, but I could not write in the folder in the container because `ls -l` shows that it belongs to user `nobody` and group `nobody`.

How to know the ID of this user and group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the `id` command to lookup uids and gids:

```
# Get the numeric uid of the user 'nobody'
$ id -u nobody
65534

# Get the numeric gid of the user 'nobody'
$ id -g nobody
65534
```

With no options, it'll print the uid and all the gids to which the user belongs:

```
$ id nobody
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `ls` command has the option `-n` to see the IDs instead of names:

```
-n, --numeric-uid-gid      like -l, but list numeric user and group IDs
```

So I used `ls -ln`, which showed me the IDs:

```
65534 65534
```

Answer (score 0):

From OP's context: using containers and thus namespaces, I'll make the assumption that a user namespace is also involved and thus *nobody* and *nogroup* are not the usual *nobody* and *nogroup* user and group to be expected.

This user *nobody* might actually be the *overflow* user ID that is returned when trying to access an user ID that in not mapped in the current user namespace, rather than the actual user *nobody*. By default the overflow user ID is mapped to *nobody*.

This can possibly happen whenever the command below doesn't return the triplet 0 0 4294967295 (meaning everything is mapped, as in the initial user namespace):

```
$ cat /proc/self/uid_map 
         0          0 4294967295
$ cat /proc/self/gid_map 
         0          0 4294967295
```

Here's the relevant paragraph of [user_namespaces(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/user_namespaces.7):

[Unmapped user and group IDs](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/user_namespaces.7#Unmapped_user_and_group_IDs)

> There are various places where an **unmapped user ID (group ID)** may
> be exposed to user space. For example, the first process in a new user
> namespace may call getuid(2) before a user ID mapping has been defined
> for the namespace. In most such cases, **an unmapped user ID is
> converted to the overflow user ID (group ID); the default value for
> the overflow user ID (group ID) is 65534.** See the descriptions of
> `/proc/sys/kernel/overflowuid` and `/proc/sys/kernel/overflowgid` in
> [proc(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/proc.5).
>
> The cases where unmapped IDs are mapped in this fashion include system
> calls that return user IDs ([getuid(2)](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/getuid.2), [getgid(2)](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/getgid.2), and similar),
> credentials passed over a UNIX domain socket, credentials returned by
> stat(2), waitid(2),
>
> [...]

One easy example to see this is when starting a new user namespace without any mapping with `unshare -U`, be it from root or from a non-privileged user. Showing here from initial host real root to have more liberty and alter `overflowuid` later:

```
root@host:~# newgrp daemon
root@host:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=1(daemon) groups=1(daemon),0(root)
root@host:~# id bin
uid=2(bin) gid=2(bin) groups=2(bin)
root@host:~# id sys
uid=3(sys) gid=3(sys) groups=3(sys)
root@host:~# touch /tmp/foo
root@host:~# chown bin:sys /tmp/foo
root@host:~# ls -l /tmp/foo; ls -n /tmp/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 bin sys 0 Oct 11 21:34 /tmp/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 2 3 0 Oct 11 21:34 /tmp/foo
root@host:~# unshare -U
nobody@host:~$ id
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
nobody@host:~$ ls -l /tmp/foo; ls -n /tmp/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 0 Oct 11 21:34 /tmp/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 65534 65534 0 Oct 11 21:34 /tmp/foo
nobody@host:~$ exit
logout
root@host:~# sysctl -w kernel.overflowuid=60000
kernel.overflowuid = 60000
root@host:~# sysctl -w kernel.overflowgid=61000
kernel.overflowgid = 61000
root@host:~# unshare -U
$ id
uid=60000 gid=61000 groups=61000
$ ls -l /tmp/foo; ls -n /tmp/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 60000 61000 0 Oct 11 21:34 /tmp/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 60000 61000 0 Oct 11 21:34 /tmp/foo
$ exit
logout
root@host:~#
```

So the reality is more complex. Inside a container displaying an overflow UID/GID there's no way to know for sure which was the actual UID/GID existing in parent namespace if it wasn't mapped to a distinct value. Here, the overflow values 60000 and 61000, which replaced the default values 65534, won't point back to the original UID/GID from parent namespace: did they stand for 0(root), 1(daemon), 2(bin), 3(sys) or even something else? No way to know.